# Why cannot import org.springframework.data cannot be resolved

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

> I get an error in he "import org.springframework.data cannot be
> resolved" in following code
> package com.steinko.reactsprinboottutorial.RestfulWebService;

```
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import java.util.List;


@Repository
public interface TodoRepository extends  CrudRepository<Todo, Long>{
    List<Todo> findByName(String Name);
    
}
```

> The gradle build.gradle looks like

```
plugins { 
              id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.3.3.RELEASE'
              id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.10.RELEASE'    
      }
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
    mavenLocal()
   // maven { url "http://dl.bintray.com/epam/reportportal" }
}

sourceCompatibility = '14'

sourceSets {
    intTest {
        compileClasspath += sourceSets.main.output
        runtimeClasspath += sourceSets.main.output
    }
}

configurations {
    intTestImplementation.extendsFrom implementation
        intTestCompile.extendsFrom testCompile
    intTestRuntimeOnly.extendsFrom runtimeOnly
}

dependencies {
     //implementation 'com.epam.reportportal:logger-java-log4j:5.0.2'
     implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
     implementation  'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
     implementation 'org.modelmapper:modelmapper:2.3.8'
     // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.validation/validation-api
     compile group: 'javax.validation', name: 'validation-api', version: '2.0.1.Final'
     implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation'
     
     runtimeOnly 'org.postgresql:postgresql'
     
     
     // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testcontainers/testcontainers
     testCompile group: 'org.testcontainers', name: 'testcontainers', version: '1.15.0-rc1'
     testCompile group: 'org.testcontainers', name: 'postgresql', version: '1.15.0-rc1'
     testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test' 
     testImplementation 'io.rest-assured:spring-mock-mvc:4.3.1'
     testImplementation  'io.rest-assured:rest-assured-common:4.3.1'
     testImplementation  'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
     testCompile group: 'org.modelmapper', name: 'modelmapper', version: '2.3.8'

     
     testImplementation 'com.epam.reportportal:agent-java-junit5:5.0.0-RC-1'
     
     intTestCompile group: 'org.testcontainers', name: 'testcontainers', version: '1.15.0-rc1'
     intTestCompile group: 'org.testcontainers', name: 'postgresql', version: '1.15.0-rc1'
     
     intTestImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
     intTestImplementation 'io.rest-assured:spring-mock-mvc:4.1.2'
     intTestImplementation 'com.epam.reportportal:agent-java-junit5:5.0.0-RC-1'
     intTestRuntimeOnly 'org.postgresql:postgresql'
}

test {
   // testLogging.showStandardStreams = true
    useJUnitPlatform()
   // systemProperty 'junit.jupiter.extensions.autodetection.enabled', true
}


task integrationTest(type: Test) {
    description = 'Runs integration tests.'
    group = 'verification'

    testClassesDirs = sourceSets.intTest.output.classesDirs
    classpath = sourceSets.intTest.runtimeClasspath
    shouldRunAfter test
}
```

> When I run the test for the service I get a nullpointer for repository
> TodoServiceTest > shoulCreateTodo() FAILED
> java.lang.NullPointerException at TodoServiceTest.java:55
> TodoServiceTest > shouldDeleteTodo() FAILED
> java.lang.NullPointerException at TodoServiceTest.java:48

```
package com.steinko.reactsprinboottutorial.RestfulWebService;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Disabled;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertNotNull;

import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.*;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.hasProperty;
import static org.hamcrest.collection.IsIterableContainingInAnyOrder.containsInAnyOrder;
import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;


public class TodoServiceTest {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TodoServiceTest.class);
    
  
    private TodoService service = new TodoService();
    
    
    @Test
    void ShouldExist() {
        assertNotNull (service);
    }
    
    
    @Test
    void shouldDeleteTodo() {
        service.deleteTodo("stein", 1L);     
    }
    
    @Test
    void shoulCreateTodo() {
        Date date = DateFactory.generetDate("01-01-2020 12:00:00"); 
        TodoDto  todo = new TodoDto(1,"Stein","Fix Kjakk", date,false);
        service.createTodo(todo);
        
    }
    
}
```

> The service test looks like

```
package com.steinko.reactsprinboottutorial.RestfulWebService;
    
    import java.text.ParseException;
    import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Date;
    import java.util.List;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    
    
    import java.util.Set;
    
    import javax.validation.ConstraintViolation;
    import javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException;
    import javax.validation.Validation;
    import javax.validation.Validator;
    
    
    import org.slf4j.Logger;
    import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
    
    
    
    @Service
    public class TodoService  {
        
        private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TodoService.class);
        
        @Autowired
        private TodoRepository repository;
        
        
        
    
        public List<TodoDto> getTodos(String name) { 
            
             List<Todo> todos = repository.findByName(name);
             TodoConverter converter = new TodoConverter(); 
             List<TodoDto> dtos =  converter.convertToDtos(todos);
             return dtos;
        }
    
        public void deleteTodo(String name, Long id) {
            repository.deleteById(id);
            
        }
    
    
    
        public void createTodo(TodoDto dto) {
            TodoConverter converter = new TodoConverter();
            Todo todo = converter.convertToEntity(dto);
            validateEntity(todo);
            repository.save(todo);
        }
        
        
        private void validateEntity(Todo todo) {
            List<String> errorMessage = new ArrayList<>();
            Validator validator = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory().getValidator();
    
            Set<ConstraintViolation<Todo>> constraintViolations = validator.validate(todo);
    
            for (ConstraintViolation<Todo> constraintViolation : constraintViolations) {
                errorMessage.add(constraintViolation.getMessage());
            }
    
            if (errorMessage.size() > 0) {
                throw new ConstraintViolationException(constraintViolations);
            }
        }
    }
```

> How do I get  access to org.springframework.data and an object at repository variabel ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to annotate the test class with either @SpringBootTest or @DataJpaTest so the repository will be initialised and injected into your service. Furthermore, you have to autowire your service in the test, or the repository will not be injected in the instance created by you.